# How to add event listener to RatingBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to get the current value of RatingBar android when there is a touch dragged on the ratings bar

I know I can do like this

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), rating + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

But I want to get the rating while changing

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more the problem ? i mean, what are you trying to archieve, and are you using any library ?

Comment: no Im not using any other library .. its android's native RatingBar. and i want to have an event to be triggered when i'm changing the ratings of the RatingBar. Not after change has been made.

Comment: so, while you are changing the rating you want to launch an action, im right ?

Comment: while changing i want to set that value into a progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this

```
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float rating = ratingBar.getRating();

        //todo: do stuff with 'rating' value
        //...

        return ratingBar.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

this will get you the rating while you are touching the `ratingBar`, and then you can pass this value into your `progressBar`